# C#: XML serialization of class that contains list of generics

Tags: c#, generics, xmlserializer

I wonder if there is any way to serialize to xml a class that contains list of generics?
It looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new ContainerClass();
        o.Values = new List<SomeClass> {new SomeClass<int>(), new SomeClass<long>()};

        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContainerClass));
        MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(buffer))
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, o); // InvalidOperationException here
        }
        var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
    }
}

public class ContainerClass
{
    public List<SomeClass> Values { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
}

public class SomeClass<T> : SomeClass
{
}
```

I know that there is a way to pass extra types to the serializer, but there is no way to now every combination that could probably appear.

I've tried to implement IXmlSerializable i various ways without success.

Any idea how to deal with it?

I am also open for external libraries if there is any that can handle it.

Comment: I wonder if it would work to set generic constraints on IXMLSerializable. eg `public class SomeClass<T> : SomeClass where T : IXMLSerializable....` (and make sure that everything is serializable.)

Comment: No difference. But it seems to me that the "Yet Another XML Serialization Library for the .NET Framework" do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [YAXLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/yaxlib.aspx) which does the job.

Answer (score 1):

After trying few libraries, I decided to code my own:

[Atlas Xml Serializer](https://github.com/Atlas-Project/AtlasXmlSerializer)

Get the dll under binaries folder and add it to your project. Then your code should work like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new ContainerClass();
        o.Values = new List<SomeClass> {new SomeClass<int>(), new SomeClass<long>()};

        var xml = Atlas.Xml.Serializer.Serialize(o, true);
    }
}

public class ContainerClass
{
    public List<SomeClass> Values { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
}

public class SomeClass<T> : SomeClass
{
}
```

Output will be similar to this:

```
<ContainerClass>
    <Values>
        <item _type="WinformsTestApp.SomeClass`1[[System.Int32]], WinformsTestApp" />
        <item _type="WinformsTestApp.SomeClass`1[[System.Int64]], WinformsTestApp" />
    </Values>
</ContainerClass>
```

PS: WinformsTestApp is my test appilcations name, so it'll change to reflect your assembly name.